# Given a string, how do I know if it needs decoding

Tags: python, base64

I'm using python's base64 module and I get a string that can be encoded or not encoded. I would like to do something like:

```
if isEncoded(s):
   output = base64.decodestring(s)
else:
   output = s
```

ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In general, it's impossible; if you receive string 'MjMj', for example, how could you possibly know whether it's already decoded and needs to be used as is, or decoded into '23#'?

Comment: exactly: you can only test that there aren't forbidden chars and that the length is divisible by four.

Comment: it's also worth noting that because it's impossible, attempting to decode it "when necessary" can be used as an attack vector for XSS and similar attacks by crafting seemingly-encoded data that your system does bad things with after its decoded.

Answer (score 5):

You could just try it, and see what happens:

```
import base64

def decode_if_necessary(s):
    try:
         return base64.decodestring(s)
    except:
         return s
```

But you have to ask yourself: what if the original message was in fact a syntactically valid base64 string, but not meant to be one? Then "decoding" it will succeed, but the result is not the required output. So I have to ask: is this *really* what you want?

**Edit:** Note that [`decodestring`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/base64.html#base64.decodestring) is deprecated.

Comment: you're saying that if s isn't decoded, decodestring() raises an exception?

Comment: He's saying that the chances of a string you want to use being validly base64 encoded are slim, and when you call `decodestring` on an invalidly base64 encoded string, `decodestring` raises an exception. This looks to me like a reasonable, simple approach. +1

Comment: I actually tried something like that and when the string, that was not decoded, did not throw an exception, I got gibrish.

Comment: Then the input you supplied was in fact a valid base64 encoding. This demonstrates the issue at hand.

Answer (score 5):

You could check to see if a string [may be base64 encoded](https://www.theeggeadventure.com/wikimedia/index.php/IsBase64).  In general, the function can predict with 75%+ accuracy is the data is encoded.

```
def isBase64(s):
    return (len(s) % 4 == 0) and re.match('^[A-Za-z0-9+/]+[=]{0,2}$', s)
```

Comment: This function was pretty much useless for me, avoid.

Comment: Elaborate please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the argument validate=True, something like:

```
  try:
    # Convert the input string to bytes
    input_bytes = input_string.encode('utf-8')

    # Decode the Base64 encoded bytes
    decoded_bytes = base64.b64decode(input_bytes, validate=True)

    return decoded_bytes
except binascii.Error:
    print("Error: Invalid Base64 string")
```

validate=True argument in the base64.b64decode() function will enforce strict padding rules (an encoded string is always properly padded). If the input string is not valid, a binascii.Error exception is raised, which we catch and handle accordingly.